# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build inside a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this StreamBuilder to get the current location:

```
StreamBuilder<UserLocation>(
            stream: locationService.locationStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {

                bool es_actual = ubicacionesProvider.ubicacionActualSeleccionada;
                bool es_elegida = ubicacionesProvider.ubicacionElegidaSeleccionada;


                if(es_actual){
                  latitudData = snapshot.data.latitude;
                 // ubicacionesProvider.setlatitudActual(latitudData);
                  longitudData = snapshot.data.longitude;
                  //ubicacionesProvider.setlongitudActual(longitudData);
                  Coordinates misCoordenadas =
                  new Coordinates(latitudData, longitudData);
                 // ubicacionesProvider.setubicacionActual(_miDireccionActual);
                  getAddress(misCoordenadas);


                }
                if(es_elegida){
                  _latitudElegida = ubicacionesProvider.latitudElegida;
                  _longitudElegida = ubicacionesProvider.longitudElegida;
                  _miDireccionActual = ubicacionesProvider.ubicacionElegida;

                }
                
              }
```

I want to update a provider called ubicacionesProvider with some changes:

```
ubicacionesProvider.setlatitudActual(latitudData)
ubicacionesProvider.setlongitudActual(longitudData)
ubicacionesProvider.setubicacionActual(_miDireccionActual)
```

But I am getting a warning using one or all of them, the app is not exiting but the warning is shown:

```
======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for UbicacionesProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This _InheritedProviderScope<UbicacionesProvider> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _InheritedProviderScope<UbicacionesProvider>
  value: Instance of 'UbicacionesProvider'
  listening to value
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: StreamBuilder<UserLocation>
  dirty
  dependencies: [MediaQuery]
  state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<UserLocation, AsyncSnapshot<UserLocation>>#39568
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4292:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4307:6)
#2      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.markNeedsNotifyDependents (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:496:5)
#3      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:226:25)
#4      UbicacionesProvider.setlatitudActual (package:flutter_qplan/providers/ubicaciones_provider.dart:50:5)
...
The UbicacionesProvider sending notification was: Instance of 'UbicacionesProvider'
====================================================================================================
```

I would like to update the provider without getting that warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens when you `setState` or `notifyListeners` before the `build` has finished building all the widgets. Maybe you can add your update logic like this :

```dart
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              // Add Your Update Code here.
            });
```